# App crashes and no error in console

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app crashes, tries searching it with breakpoints but still can not find it. Also tried the all exeptions on throw but still goes to the main:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
```

Tried deleting all what is inside the unwindSegue that is called, but still crashes like 1-2 seconds afterwards I've pressed the button and the method is activated.

Is there a way I can find the error with the other tools of Xcode ? I'm fairy new to debugging and error finding.

EDIT:
Crash log when NSZombiesEnabled:

```
*** -[DetailViewController alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x162d2b00
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the crash log?

Comment: On the upper right of your Xcode you will see three icons. Push the one in the middle, copy and paste everything thats in that black box at the bottom, and edit it into your OP.

Comment: There is no crash log. The app just stops. Added an image of the crash of xCode.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem this morning. In my case, I was deallocating a UIWindow while doing a unwind segue. For whatever reason, delaying the deallocation (by delaying setting the pointer to nil) by 3 seconds fixed my crash. My guess is the exception was thrown somewhere in an Apple framework, but I can't say for certain.

Unfortunately, the solution also involved commenting out code and re-running the app until I found the offending line of code (other solutions that said to install unhandled exception handlers or signal handlers didn't work for me).

Other things I've read that can cause this are extremely large memory allocations (someone tried to NSLog many megabytes of data).

Good luck with your hunt.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is way in xcode to find the crash. For that you need to enable the NSZombie inside the edit scheme in the xcode.

Note:- After enabling NSZombie will show crash logs only for retain or release of object for other exception it will not show any logs.

Comment: Oke thanks for the information! Enabled it and my crash log says this: `*** -[DetailViewController alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x162d2b00`

Comment: Yes it means your DetailViewController instance is getting released. Now the question here. How did you declared your DetailViewController instance ??

Comment: So the user presses an delete button in the navigation bar, and gets an UIAlertView for confirmation. When pressed on yes the following segue will be performed: `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"deleteDice" sender:self];`